# How to search single field in mongoDB using querymen?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I'm currently developing a REST API using this generator.

https://github.com/diegohaz/rest?fbclid=IwAR3FwvhJuKpAtCrywOIRkpts8ZvZ_36Gk9b8ksSv2_MEgFtJnl4G7QZvGNI

But I'm kind of new with the MEAN stack environment especially mongoDB.

I just want to ask how to use the search query parameter described in this auto generated document of my project.

https://www.screencast.com/t/4wR7qyxj5ZP

I'm trying to search all the menu by list_id

for MYSQL something like this.

```
Select * from menu where list_id = '123';
```

So this generated REST API application is using querymen for search query. I already tried www.domain.com/menus?q={list_id:"1"}, www.domain.com/menus?q={"list_id":"1"} but none of this works it only shows empty results.

Here's my the router part of the code.

```
/**
 * @api {get} /menus Retrieve menus
 * @apiName RetrieveMenus
 * @apiGroup Menu
 * @apiUse listParams
 * @apiSuccess {Object[]} menus List of menus.
 * @apiError {Object} 400 Some parameters may contain invalid values.
 */

router.get('/',
  query({ limit: { max: 1000 } }),
  index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my question just in case someone has the same problem. So I figured out that I just need to include a custom schema in the query parameter so instead of

```
router.get('/',
query({ limit: { max: 1000 } }),
index)
```

It is now like this.

```
query({
  list_id: {
    type: String,
    paths: ['list_id']
  },
  limit: { max: 1000 }
}),index)
```

You can also change the String to Regexp if you want.